# Is frequent update of widget possible in API level 8 possible

Tags: android, android-widget, alarmmanager

I want to update my widget every 5 sec. Is it possible in API level 8?

Comment: look at this once:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666311/update-appwidget-periodically-from-a-service/5847101#5847101

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible to update the widget frequently not only in API level 8 ,we can do it in all the API level . But approach to do so is will be different. Like u have to make use of handler or separate thread or trigger event something similar to that.